# I want to update the last action's time in every page, where should it be?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I try to use MVC architecture to create my project. And I want to update last action's time user made in every page.

I could have a code in footer.php something like this:

```
update_query("users", "time=NOW()", "WHERE userId = {$_SESSION['id']}");
```

So every time user refreshes any page, his time would update. Obviously it's not good practise to put that in View. So, what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: usually make ajax call on each event instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. I would put it in footer.php or any code that's displayed on every page - maybe a common.php or something that happens after the authentication.

I would not use AJAX for this because it's an extra call to the server/database that isn't required. I try and keep queries to the server to a minimum.

Also, make sure you sanitize the input (case the $_SESSION['id'] as an int before inserting it into the database), this will eliminate any possible security issues with the query.

```
update_query('users', 'time=NOW()', 'WHERE userId = ' . (int) $_SESSION['id']);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure putting this in footer.php is a bad idea.

Comment: You could always put it in authentication since it has to update the session time every time a page is loaded, that would be an excellent place to put it.